# conditional formatting to apply to all rows

Tags: excel, gantt-chart

I have a Gantt Chart and I need it to change color if my formula applies.
The formula is to see if the number "2"(from column G) & the number "1"(from the Gantt Chart) occur at the same time (apply for each day). 
If it does, then only part of the Gantt phase(AKA "1") will change color.
I got everything right except it only works on 1 row (out of over 200)
[image]

The formula is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($G$17:$G$17=2)*(AI17:AI17=1))=1
```

and it applies to the whole row, but I need it to apply to the whole table.
when I try to do that it goes crazy and changes other rows that don't comply to the formula.
I really don't want to make a conditional formatting to each of the 200 rows.
Any ideas?

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT(($G17:$G17=2)*(AI17:AI17=1))=1` works for me applied to `=$AI$17:$VI$200`. But `=AND($G17=2,AI17=1)` also applied to `=$AI$17:$VI$200` should be the same.

Comment: thank you!! very smart and yet so simple!!